# Will static registration lead to a fiasco

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I would like that some classes (say sources) automatically register themselves into another one (say destination). My first idea was to declare a static instance of destination class, and use initialization of a static field in source class.

For the real problem, it would be to automatically declare classes representing Windows in a Windows GUI program, to a singleton object representing the application, so that the initialization of the application object be able to register all windows classes (in the WIN32 sense).

I could write a Proof Of Concept that compiles and runs without even a warning (MSVC 2008, gcc 4.8.2, Clang 3.5) but I wonder whether it is really correct or just undefined behaviour due the the static initialization fiasco. I only found [In C++, Is it good form to write code that executes before main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110976/) in SO that could be loosely related to my problem.

Short story (full compilable source below) :

I have a destination class say A with a inner Node class (simply linked list of pointers), a `Node *head` field and a registerName method.

```
class A {
    ...
    Node * head; // should be NULL
    static A instance;
    ...
```

I declare a static instance of A with that C++ fragment :

```
A A::instance;

bool A::registerName(const char *name) {
    std::cout << "Register " << name << std::endl;
    Node *node = new Node(name, head);
    head = node;
    return true;
}
```

Then I register a source classes (say C) containing a static char* name by initializing a static boolean :

```
const char C::name[] = "ClassC";
bool C::inited = A::getInstance().registerName(C::name);
```

The question is:

As the initialization of static `bool C::inited` depends on the static `A A::instance` will it lead to UB because of the static initialization fiasco, or is is still correct because I only need that in A instance the `head` pointer to be initialized to NULL (and that initialization may occur before any constructor to be called)  ?

TL/DR : Full source :

Destination class :

```
class A
{
    class Node {
        const char *name;
        Node *next;
    public:
        Node(const char *name = 0, Node *next = 0): name(name),
            next(next) {};
        const char* getName() const { return name; }
        Node * getNext() const { return next; }

    };

    Node *head;

    static A instance;

    A() {};
    ~A();

public:
    static A& getInstance() { return instance; }

    Node *getHead() const { return head; }

    bool registerName(const char *name);
    friend int main();
};
```

Implementation

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>

A::~A(void)
{
    Node *next;
    while (head != 0) {
        next = head ->getNext();
        std::cout << "Delete Node for " << head->getName() << std::endl;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
}

A A::instance;

bool A::registerName(const char *name) {
    std::cout << "Register " << name << std::endl;
    Node *node = new Node(name, head);
    head = node;
    return true;
}
```

Destination classes (3 different files) :

```
#include "A.h"

class B
{
protected:
    static bool inited;
    static const char name[];

    B() {};
    virtual ~B() {};
};
```

//

```
#include "B.h"

class C :
    public B
{
protected:
    static bool inited;
    static const char name[];

public:
    C() {};
    virtual ~C() {};
};
```

//

```
#include "B.h"

class D :
    public B
{
protected:
    static bool inited;
    static const char name[];

public:
    D() {};
    virtual ~D() {};
};
```

Implementation (2 files) :

```
#include "C.h"

const char C::name[] = "ClassC";
bool C::inited = A::getInstance().registerName(C::name);
```

//

```
#include "D.h"

const char D::name[] = "ClassD";
bool D::inited = A::getInstance().registerName(D::name);
```

Main file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A& instance = A::getInstance();
    A::Node* node = instance.getHead();
    while (node != NULL) {
        std::cout << node->getName() << std::endl;
        node = node->getNext();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Register ClassC
Register ClassD
ClassD
ClassC
Delete Node for ClassD
Delete Node for ClassC
```

Comment: Even if it does work it seems like a recipe for disaster...

Comment: @MattMcNabb : That's the reason why I ask here ! Without a confirmation that the `head` pointer will be created with a null value and will be available at initialization time I would not dare use that in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent problems due to initialization order, implement singletons as static variables inside a function. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/construct-on-first-use-v2.html .

In your case, the use of singletons for registering window classes is somehow surprising. Never a good thing for maintainable code. Maybe better manually register all window-classes inside your application class, e.g. by a hardcoded table of initialization functions. The event loop should not be run inside the constructor of Application as this would prevent extension, but instead e.g. in an Application method.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I know that my present code is border line, and I understand that I could (should ?) avoid that. I was rather surprised that it worked on 3 different compilers and wondered whether it was just *by chance* ...

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mainly an addition to Markus's one with an implementation example.

For the static A `instance`, I use :

- a static function to define the instance (from Markus's answer) :

  ```
  static A& getInstance() {
      static A _instance;

      return _instance;
  }
  ```
- a static reference in A class: `A& instance` (to be used as a cache inside the class) defined in implementation file with :

  ```
  A& A::instance = A::getInitInstance();
  ```

For the registration of source classes I managed to put all the registration logic into a template base class :

```
template<typename T> // T will be the actual subclass
class Base {
protected:
    static bool registerSelf() {
        A::registerClass(T::name);
        return true;
    }
    Base() {
        if (! inited) { // force an access to inited
            registerSelf(); // never executed in my tests
        }
    }
    static const bool inited;
};
template<typename T> // in the .h as it is a template
const bool Base<T>::inited = Base<T>::registerSelf();
```

The derived classes have only to define a `static const char * name`, but (at least in MSVC 2008) it must be public or `Base<T>::registerSelf();` must be explicitely declared friend (anyway it could make sense to have it public) :

```
class C: public Base<C> {
public:
    static const char name[];

    // friend bool Base<C>::registerSelf(); if name is not public
};

const char C::name[] = "foo"; // in implementation file
```

That way, all subclasses that are actually used anywhere in the program are registered, without any risk for the *static initialization fiasco* (thanks to Markus), and in my tests, if a class is declared but not used it is not registered